# How to make common authorization call in SecurityConfig class to authorize every request in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring Boot Security. I am performing validation of licenseKey in every end-point in REST call. It is working fine.
I want to do it in a common way like `SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}` class so that I should not pass extra parameter in methods for validation. It means there should be common validation if the licenseKey exists then the REST calls should be authorized to go otherwise, it should throw error. Currently I am passing HttpServletRequest which contains licenseKey, the methods are working fine. But our requirement is to perform only in one place in SecurityConfig so that all the requests can be validated.

```
@GetMapping(path="some/path")
public ResponseEntity<> viewDetails(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, MappingVO mappingVO) {

    String licenseUser = userDetailsService.getLicenseUser(httpRequest).getUser().getEmailAddress();
    ....
    ....
}

@DeleteMapping(path="some/path")
public ResponseEntity<> deletePart(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, Part part) {

    String licenseUser = userDetailsService.getLicenseUser(httpRequest).getUser().getEmailAddress();
    ....
    ....
}

In class CustomUserDetails, it has been written like this.

public CustomUserDetails getLicenseUser(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        String userId = httpRequest.getHeader("licenseKey");
        CustomUserDetails ud = (CustomUserDetails) loadUserByUsername(userId);
        return ud;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a custom filter in the filter chain in your security config that executes before each request.

Just create a Custom Filter implementing OncePerRequestFilter.java and do the license Key validation inside of that filter. The implementation logic inside your Custom filter will run once before each request that is made on your spring boot server.

Refer

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-onceperrequestfilter

https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-add-filter/

If you are using Spring Security and want to filter requests to verify that it has valid token passed to it (if you're not already doing this), refer to the official documentation of your respective version of spring security to see where should you add your filter inside the filterChain.

Check Filter Ordering in:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/security-filter-chain.html

The token validation filter should ideally be exeucted before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.